# Why Visual Studio 2015 doesn't use the new projects' reference?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I'm working on a company's solution. 
Due to the big size of the solution, we normally:

- download only the projects we need to change the code in (let's say project X and Y)
- download the assemblies of the other non-modifiable projects ((let's say project A and B).

All the solution references are put in a separate folder ("c:\DEV\bin" for example).

Let's say that project X depends on project Y, (as well as A&B). By default, when the projects are newly downloaded, it is normal that X references the assemblies of projects Y, A and B that are in the separate folder.

But once projects Y's code is changed locally and rebuilt, X should now reference the Y's assembly that is in the workspace, not the old one that is "c:\DEV\bin". Thing that does not happen because project X still points to the old assembly.

What actions or configurations should I do, so that the projects reference the newly built assemblies?

Comment: did you tried clean the solution and rebuild it ?

Comment: @ErtanTuran yes, I did.